# Node Express + CSS

Tags: css, node.js, express

I am requesting a single EJS file (setting Express, Request).

```
app.get('/space', function(req, res){
    res.render('space.ejs');
});
```

The file actually renders but only two of three CSS stylesheet link are work when opening the page with my node app. The link that does not work is W3 school. (the only http of all three, could that be the reason?)
However, the all three links work when I open the file directly in browser.

Could someone explain this behavior?

Here is the .ejs file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS Template</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<html>
```

Comment: i suggest you to open that css url in browser and save that css file locally and load that local file in your ejs page.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason it doesn't work. I have set ``app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`` and the w3.css file in public/css/ but w3.css won't read from the ejs file, where I direct to ``<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/w3.css"/>``. Do I need to make a specific request ``app.get('/space'css/w3.css, //etc.``?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/w3.css"/> you need to add "static" in link tag <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/w3.css"/> and try now

Comment: Hey Vinay. That actually didn't work. I found the solution to my problem. ``app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))`` needed be ``app.use(express.static(process.cwd() + '/public'));`` for the specific of my case, as the server.js file is in a /lib folder inside the /app folder. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you server.js file was in another folder that is why it is not working other wise its works. you did process.cwd() so it can file public folder path and its working for you. if my answer helps you than let me know i will post answer and mark my answer.

Comment: i have posted answer combining your solution please mark my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be trying to access an insecure resource over a secure connection, if your site is on https you cannot request an http asset. Try changingnthe w3 link to https. It could also be CORS blocked, do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Thanks. I can't change the link to https. it won't work. No error message in the console. I don't manage to read the file from my server on Heroku for some unknown reason. I have set ``app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`` and the w3.css file in public/css/ but won't read from the ejs file, where I direct to ``<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/w3.css"/>``

Comment: Thanks it was helpful to understand I could not request http from https server

Answer (score 0):

you have written

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/w3.css"/>` 
you need to add "static" in link tag
 `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/w3.css"/>` and it should work for you.

in your case your server.js file in lib dir that is why you should do this

```
app.use(express.static(process.cwd() + '/public'));
```